# Loop over rows with date and other conditions

Tags: python, pandas

```
Date          Product   Quantity
01.01.2020    Apple        1
02.01.2020    Apple        2
03.01.2020    Apple        3
04.01.2020    Apple        7
05.01.2020    Orange       8
06.01.2020    Orange       1
07.01.2020    Orange       7
08.01.2020    Orange       9
```

My requirement is

```
Date          Product   Quantity   Output
01.01.2020    Apple        1         12 (2+3+7)
02.01.2020    Apple        2         10 (3+7+0)
03.01.2020    Apple        3         7
04.01.2020    Apple        7         0
05.01.2020    Orange       8         17 (1+7+9)
06.01.2020    Orange       1         16 (7+9)
07.01.2020    Orange       7         9
08.01.2020    Orange       9         0
```

I want quantity sum for next three days, product wise. Output Expected is given in the last column

Answer (score 2):

You can try of either [rolling sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) or [Cummulative sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) on individual grouped, reversed series

```
#df['Output'] = df.groupby('Product')['Quantity'].apply(lambda x: x[::-1].rolling(3,min_periods=1).sum()[::-1].shift(-1).fillna(0)).tolist()
df['Output'] = df.groupby('Product')['Quantity'].apply(lambda x: x[::-1].cumsum()[::-1].shift(-1).fillna(0)).tolist()
```

Out:

```
Date    Product Quantity    Output
0   2020-01-01  Apple   1   12.0
1   2020-02-01  Apple   2   10.0
2   2020-03-01  Apple   3   7.0
3   2020-04-01  Apple   7   0.0
4   2020-05-01  Orange  8   17.0
5   2020-06-01  Orange  1   16.0
6   2020-07-01  Orange  7   9.0
7   2020-08-01  Orange  9   0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, But I want cumulative sum based on date range condition. Not rolling sum

Comment: you can simply change the function to cumsum, added the change :)

Comment: please check the answer `df.groupby('Product')['Quantity'].apply(lambda x: x[::-1].cumsum()[::-1].shift(-1).fillna(0)).tolist()`

Comment: data = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    start_date = row['date'] + relativedelta(days=1)
    end_date = row['date'] + relativedelta(days=4)
    sum = df.loc[(df['date'] >= start_date) & (df['date'] < end_date)]['Quantity'].agg('sum')
    data.update({row['date'] : [sum]})

# collect data into new df
df_final = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index', columns=['Quantity'])
print(df_final)

Comment: My requirement is adding next three days only. If date is not available in the date range (i.e 3 days), it should not add.

Comment: Your Intention is not clear @BALAJIR , 3day summation cant be possible with cumsum except rolling, but you asked for

Comment: cumsum is what I expected but with date restriction

Comment: date          Product   Quantity   Output
01.01.2020     Apple       1         9 (2+3+4)
02.01.2020     Apple       2         7 (3+4)  
03.01.2020     Apple       3         4
04.01.2020     Apple       4         0
01.02.2020     Apple       5         6
02.02.2020     Apple       6         0
01.01.2020     Grapes      7         8
02.01.2020     Grapes      8         0
03.02.2020     Grapes      9         0

Comment: This is what I expected

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import io
import pandas

s="""Date          Product   Quantity
01.01.2020    Apple        1
02.01.2020    Apple        2
03.01.2020    Apple        3
04.01.2020    Apple        7
05.01.2020    Orange       8
06.01.2020    Orange       1
07.01.2020    Orange       7
08.01.2020    Orange       9
"""

df = pandas.read_fwf(io.StringIO(s))

Output = list()
for grp in df.groupby('Product'):
    df_grp = grp[1].copy()
    df_grp['day1'] = df_grp.Quantity.shift(-1)
    df_grp['day2'] = df_grp.Quantity.shift(-2)
    df_grp['day3'] = df_grp.Quantity.shift(-3)
    df_grp.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df_grp['Output'] = df_grp.day1 + df_grp.day2 + df_grp.day3
    for cnt in df_grp.Output:
        Output.append(int(cnt))
df['Output'] = Output
df
```

Result:

```
         Date Product  Quantity  Output
0  01.01.2020   Apple         1      12
1  02.01.2020   Apple         2      10
2  03.01.2020   Apple         3       7
3  04.01.2020   Apple         7       0
4  05.01.2020  Orange         8      17
5  06.01.2020  Orange         1      16
6  07.01.2020  Orange         7       9
7  08.01.2020  Orange         9       0
```

Comment: Thanks, But I want cumulative sum based on date range condition. Not rolling sum

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over rows, you can use this structure:

```
for index,row in df.iterrrows():
    df.loc[index,'output'] = df.loc[index+1,'Quantity'] + df.loc[index+2,'Quantity'] + df.loc[index+3,'Quantity']
```